# MaltParser cannot find configuration file if it is not in current directory

Tags: java, nlp

I have trained a model using `maltparser` version 1.8.1, and I can parse text just fine, but I tried to do it from a non-local directory,

```
java -Xmx6G -jar /Users/me/maltparser-1.8.1/maltparser-1.8.1.jar -c /Users/me/maltparser-1.8.1/configFile -m parse
```

and I get the following error:

`Couldn't find the MaltParser configuration file: /Users/me/maltparser-1.8.1/configFile.mco`

However, the file definitely exists. I copied the text from the error:

```
$ ls /Users/me/maltparser-1.8.1/configFile.mco
/Users/me/maltparser-1.8.1/configFile.mco
```

The only way that I can get it to work is if I run java in the directory where the configuration file is. Is there something special that I have to do to use a full path for the configuration file?

It would be possible, I suppose, to `cd` in a shell script to make this work, but I still want to understand why doing it this way doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same problem, but then I looked into the [source code](http://www.maltparser.org/download.html) and found out that you need to provide the relative path of the configuration file from the place you are executing the java command. This is because the path where you have executed the program is prepended to the path of the config file you provide as argument, unless you have mentioned the working directory as argument(in this case put the config in the working directory).